# Converting text output to object using powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to schedule a list of URL's in maintenance mode in SCOM 2007 using powershell. I am trying to get the list of URLs display name from a text file and trying to pass as input to below command.However it's not working. Can some body help how to pass the display name in text file as input

```
$URLStuff = Get-Content C:\Display.txt

$URLWatcher = (Get-MonitoringClass -name Microsoft.SystemCenter.WebApplication.Perspective) |
    Get-MonitoringObject | where {$_.DisplayName -eq $URLStuff}
```

Answer (score 0):

`get-content` is returning you an array of string objects, one per line found in the file. You need to turn your `where-object` around to search that array for the `DisplayName` of each object found from SCOM.

```
$URLWatcher = (Get-MonitoringClass -name Microsoft.SystemCenter.WebApplication.Perspective) |
    Get-MonitoringObject | where {$URLStuff -contains $_.DisplayName}
```

I'm assuming that you've already verified that `DisplayName` *does* contain the data you're looking for and will match the contents of `Display.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have made slight modification and its working now                                                  $URLStuff = Get-Content C:\Display.txt

foreach ( $eachurl in  $URLStuff)

{

$class=Get-MonitoringClass -name Microsoft.SystemCenter.WebApplication.Perspective

$URLWatcher= Get-MonitoringObject -monitoringclass:$class | where {$eachurl -match $_.DisplayName}